# How to store loaded text data

Tags: java, text, text-files

I am given three text files and have to load them sequentially, taking not of the current file loaded and the previously loaded text files.

```
data1.txt
Name    Score
Leslie  25
Pat     12
Alfred  32

data2.txt
Name    Score
Leslie  35
Keith   22
Alfred  12

data3.txt
Name    Score
Philip  38
Keith   32
Diop    22
```

Expected Output

```
Current Scores : 38, 32, 22
Current Names  : Philip, Keith, Diop

Previous Scores : 35, 22,12
Previous Names :  Leslie, Keith, Alfred
```

This is the code written to do this. It's not giving me the expected results:

```
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> currentscore = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> prevscore = new ArrayList<String>();

    String path = "C:........../question/";

    String textfile;

    File folder = new File(path);

    File [] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File folder, String name){
            return name.endsWith(".txt");               
        }
    });
    for (int ixa=0; ixa<listOfFiles.length; ixa++){

        textfile = listOfFiles[ixa].getName();
         String inputfile = textfile;
         FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(inputfile);
         BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
         String aLine1;
         while ((aLine1 = bfr1.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = aLine1.split("\t");
                name.add(split[0]); currentscore.add(split[1]);
            }
         System.out.println(name);System.out.println("Current Scores are" + currentscore);
         System.out.println("Previous Scores are" + prevscore);

         prevscore = currentscore;
         currentscore.clear();
        name.clear();
    }
```

Comment: "It is not giving me the expected results" is not very specific. Please tell what you are getting and what do you expect, and where have you pinpointed the problem.

Comment: The expected results is given in the post..

Comment: What output is it giving you?

Comment: You need to decompose your task into several parts (reading data from file, storing the data in a data structure, outputting the final data). At each of those precise, simple steps, you may have specific issues which we may help you with. But just posting a bunch of code and stating "this is the output I want" sounds a lot like "do the work/debugging for me", which is not what this site is about. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Programming problems**

- You are opening files and not closing them. You should use `bfr1.close()` after the `while` loop, or preferably use a "try with resources" to open the files.
- You should be using the `File` object itself rather than its name.
- You assign `prevscore = currentscore`, but then you clear `currentscore`. Pay attention - when you assign an object you are not assigning a copy of it. You are just putting a reference to the same object into `prevscore`. This means that when you clear it, it's cleared in `prevscore` as well. What you should be doing is:

  ```
  prevscore = currentscore;
  currentscore = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```

  This means that `prevscore` points now to what used to be `currentscore`, but now `currentscore` is pointing to a new, empty object.

**Logic problems**

- Each file has a title line. But you read the lines from the very first, so the "Name" and "Score" strings get appended to your lists. You should skip the first line of each file.
- You are not printing the names. You are supposed to. Otherwise there is no point in keeping a list of names at all.
- You are keeping a list of previous scores, but you are not keeping a list of previous names. If you're going to print them, you'll need a list of previous names.